# MySQL schema EAV one column for different value or multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, entity-attribute-value

I am running a project on MySQL 8 and PHP 7.2 on Laravel 6 framework

I have a EAV situation as this:

**page** table:

```
id | project_id | page
1  |    1       | about-us
2  |    1       | home
3  |    2       | home
```

**page_attributes** table:

```
id | page_id | attribute | type
1  |   1     | speed     | float
2  |   1     | title     | text
```

**attribute_values** table:

```
id | page_attribute_id | value
1  |        1          |   5.22
2  |        2          |   page title is this
```

Now my question is that it's better in **attribute_values** table to have just one column for both float and text types like i did or to have two separated columns one for value_text and another value_float?

And if I had more types like int, boolean,... what about then? which way is beter?

**UPDATE:**

@strawberry mentioned a way that I didn't thing of it's considered if it's better to have multiple tables for each data type
So it's now like this:

> - having one column for all data types
> - having multiple columns for each data types
> - having multiple tables for each data types

**Note: I am dealing with about 50 Million records**

Comment: are the id columns in the second two tables meant to not be unique?

Comment: @AlexHarris they are unique it's just a typo sorry

Comment: If using an EAV, I like to have separate tables for different data types

Comment: Is it faster? have you tried this before? sorry for asking I have to be sure @Strawberry

Comment: I think you could test this for yourself - but it seems like a good idea to preserve data types, where possible.